# How to exchange / switch a prop on the click of a button in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a video player component in NextJs that is populated with video links through a {videoLink} prop:

```
 <ReactPlayer playing={true} controls={true} muted={true} loop={true} width="100" height="100" 
url={videoLinkDeep} poster="images/330163_C2B_Clean.png">  </ReactPlayer>
```

The data being passed into the component consists of several different possible link props such as {videoLinkLong} or {videoLinkShort}.

The preset {videoLinkDeep) portion of the URL is now supposed to be exchanged through another video link prop such as {videoLinkLong} on the click of a button. How can I achieve this given that I start with a:

```
   <button className="bg-black">Preview Length</button>
```

Only?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use the useState hook for the url.

```
const defaultVideoLink = "Default Link";
const longVideoLink = "Long Link";
const shortVideoLink = "Short Link";
const [videoLink, setVideoLink] = useState(dafaultVideoLink);
```

Then, depending on how you want your UI to be, you can use setState to change the url. Lets say you use three different buttons,

```
<button onClick={() => setVideoLink(defaultVideoLink)}>View Default Video</button>
<button onClick={() => setVideoLink(longVideoLink)}>View Long Video</button>
<button onClick={() => setVideoLink(shortVideoLink)}>View Short Video</button>
```

Finally, your react player component will be as follows:

```
<ReactPlayer {...props} url={videoLink}></ReactPlayer>
```

You can even do a dropdown or a menu component for the UI using some libraries, but in any case, the logic will be same. Let me know if you need any further help!

Comment: Thank you! What would I set as prop for the video component initially? 
Currently it's url={videoLinkDeep}

Comment: I missed the definition of the ReactPlayer component, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: The initial value given to the videoLink is determined in the useState declaration, which in this case, is defaultVideoLink in the first code fragment. You can use any variable name and value as per your requirement.

Comment: One final question: since all links are passed as props ( such as {videoLinkLong} or {videoLinkShort} ) and not plain text, how would I need to structure the initial const setup to pass the links correclty?

Comment: If there’s only one video, you can use the same system I used and just declare three constants with string values, maybe, https:/youtube….

Comment: If there can be multiple videos and it depends on which one the user requests for, you might want to make use of props for the component.

Comment: Props are already in use as you can see in my initial question: When the default of url ist set to: {videoLinkDeep} and all other links are stored in props as well: ({videoLinkLong} or  {videoLinkShort}) wouldn't I need to adjust the const portions to work with these props as well?

Comment: You won't need to do any adjustments as far as I understand your question. Your declared default value of deep is set in the useState declarations. The other two links aka long and short, they are not called props, you can call them const variables. You just declare them and pass them on to the setter in the handler of the corresponding button and you will be just fine. Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use the hook `useState`.

Examples and documentation available: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html